# Simplifying on logic operations - discrete maths

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have this simple expression and I would be grateful if someone simplified it then told me step by step how they did so.

The question says just 'Simplify'.
Here's operation to simplify:
$$(\neg a\lor\neg b)\land(\neg b\lor\neg c)\implies(c\lor a)$$

Comment: first of all write the question here, instead of giving links. else many downvotes ahead

Comment: The question literally says 'Simplify'.

Comment: Simplify what? This site has MathJax to let you notate formulas, use it.

Comment: Use [online editor](http://hostmath.com) if you are new to Latex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression translates to the following [Karnaugh Veitch map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map):

[image]

It can thus be simplified to

> $a \lor c$